# How I can find out max and min value of each day from hourly data sets

Tags: python, pandas, max, min, resampling

This is hourly data of 2 years and I required max and min of daily data, how can I find this?

```
                     value
record ts                 
2014-01-01 00:00:00   5.83
2014-01-01 01:00:00   5.38
2014-01-01 02:00:00   4.80
2014-01-01 03:00:00   3.81
2014-01-01 04:00:00   4.46
2014-01-01 05:00:00   5.04
2014-01-01 06:00:00   5.76
2014-01-01 07:00:00   6.15
2014-01-01 08:00:00   6.66
2014-01-01 09:00:00   7.02
2014-01-01 10:00:00   7.43
2014-01-01 11:00:00   7.34
2014-01-01 12:00:00   7.24
2014-01-01 13:00:00   7.71
2014-01-01 14:00:00   8.89
2014-01-01 15:00:00  10.31
```

Comment: Please check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.aggregate.html) `min` and `max`:

```
print (df)
                     value
record ts                 
2014-01-01 00:00:00   5.83
2014-01-01 01:00:00   5.38
2014-01-01 02:00:00   4.80
2014-01-01 03:00:00   3.81
2014-01-02 04:00:00   4.46
2014-01-02 05:00:00   5.04
2014-01-02 06:00:00   5.76
2014-01-03 07:00:00   6.15
2014-01-03 08:00:00   6.66
2014-01-03 09:00:00   7.02
2014-01-03 10:00:00   7.43
2014-01-04 11:00:00   7.34
2014-01-04 12:00:00   7.24
2014-01-04 13:00:00   7.71
2014-01-05 14:00:00   8.89
2014-01-05 15:00:00  10.31

#if not DatetimeIndex
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
print (df.resample('D')['value'].agg(['min', 'max']))
             min    max
record ts              
2014-01-01  3.81   5.83
2014-01-02  4.46   5.76
2014-01-03  6.15   7.43
2014-01-04  7.24   7.71
2014-01-05  8.89  10.31
```

Another solution:

```
print (df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D'))['value'].agg(['min', 'max']))
             min    max
record ts              
2014-01-01  3.81   5.83
2014-01-02  4.46   5.76
2014-01-03  6.15   7.43
2014-01-04  7.24   7.71
2014-01-05  8.89  10.31
```

---

*** piRSquared edit, thank you***

***timing***
[image]

Comment: for what its worth: `.agg(['min', 'max'])` is 6% faster over 1,000,000 rows.

Comment: It is really interesting, wau.

Comment: As far as I understand, `[min, max]` is applying the python's `max` and `min`.  `['max', 'min']` tells `agg` to use its own optimized versions.  unutbu could explain better ;-)